# SolidCP – Install successful, but now getting issues with application pool not starting – service unavailable

Tags: web-hosting, iis, windows

Here´s my basic setup:

- Windows Server 2012 2R
- SQL Server 2016

I’ve managed to install SolidCP on the server. Had a few issues during installation, but solved it. Also completed the extra setting on the application pool and on the website configuration, as the video showed. But now, I can’t access the portal yet (http://localhost:9001). The application pools won’t start the pools for all SolidCP applications

And the error log messages (WAS) I’m getting are:
5022 - The Windows Process Activation Service failed to create a worker process for the application pool 'SolidCP Portal Pool'. The data field contains the error number.
5002 - Application pool 'SolidCP Portal Pool' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.

I’ve consulted the solidCP forum and double checked that the SolidCP users (SCPPortal, SCPEnterprise, SCPServer) on the server are member of the group IIS_IUSRS

Anyone has any idea on what I’m missing out?